# WAS 6.1, Windows 7, Error Starting and Stopping Server

Tags: websphere

Hi I had WAS 6.1 running on Windows 7 for 3-4 months without a problem and then one day it started stalling when I stopped it and it wouldn’t start backup. That has been 2 months ago or so. I have uninstalled it and reinstalled it 5 or 6 times to try and resolve the issue with no luck; same symptoms.

When I try and start the server sometimes it works and other times it doesn’t. When it doesn’t I get the following exception:

```
 Exception com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host PHXJ05308513.ads.xxx.com at port 8880
```

I have tried to go into servers.xml and change that port but it seems to have no effect. I have tried to delete the .pid file before starting as well (in the logs folder for the profile).

In addition, when I attempt to create a datasource connection (that I know works) I get :

```
 Exception attempting to get free port for status socket java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
```

I have also seen CORBA errors in the log while trying to troubleshoot this. I have read enough to know that there is a networking conflict somewhere, but I have tried many of the solutions and they don't resolve the issue.

Start Server Stack Trace:

```
    [6/29/15 18:29:21:102 GMT] 0000000a AdminTool     A   ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
[6/29/15 18:29:23:741 GMT] 0000000a AdminTool     A   ADMU3012E: Exception attempting to get free port for status socket Address already in use: NET_Bind
[6/29/15 18:29:23:741 GMT] 0000000a AdminTool     E   ADMU3012E: Exception attempting to get free port for status socket java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:331)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:197)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:109)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.initStatusPort(AdminTool.java:983)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.getStatusPort(AdminTool.java:964)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.runTool(WsServerLauncher.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.executeUtility(AdminTool.java:261)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.executeUtilityOnWindows(WsServerController.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.main(WsServerLauncher.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:263)

[6/29/15 18:29:25:441 GMT] 0000000a AdminTool     A   ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
[6/29/15 18:29:25:441 GMT] 0000000a WsServerLaunc E   ADMU3002E: Exception attempting to process server server1
[6/29/15 18:29:25:441 GMT] 0000000a WsServerLaunc E   ADMU3007E: Exception java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.waitForServerInit(WsServerController.java:208)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.runTool(WsServerLauncher.java:310)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.executeUtility(AdminTool.java:261)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.executeUtilityOnWindows(WsServerController.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.main(WsServerLauncher.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:263)

[6/29/15 18:29:25:441 GMT] 0000000a AdminTool     E   ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.waitForServerInit(WsServerController.java:208)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.runTool(WsServerLauncher.java:310)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.executeUtility(AdminTool.java:261)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.executeUtilityOnWindows(WsServerController.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.main(WsServerLauncher.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:263)

[6/29/15 18:29:25:457 GMT] 0000000a AdminTool     A   ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.waitForServerInit(WsServerController.java:208)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.runTool(WsServerLauncher.java:310)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.executeUtility(AdminTool.java:261)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.executeUtilityOnWindows(WsServerController.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.main(WsServerLauncher.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:263)
```

Stop Server Stack Trace:

```
 [6/29/15 18:31:28:858 GMT] 0000000a WsServerStop  E   ADMU3002E: Exception attempting to process server server1
[6/29/15 18:31:28:859 GMT] 0000000a WsServerStop  E   ADMU3007E: Exception com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host PHXJ05308513.ads.xxxx.com at port 8881.
[6/29/15 18:31:28:860 GMT] 0000000a WsServerStop  A   ADMU3007E: Exception com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host PHXJ05308513.ads.xxxx.com at port 8881.
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(AdminClientFactory.java:479)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.LaunchUtils.getAdminClient(LaunchUtils.java:372)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.LaunchUtils.getAdminClient(LaunchUtils.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerStop.runTool(WsServerStop.java:325)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.executeUtility(AdminTool.java:261)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.executeUtilityOnWindows(WsServerController.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerStop.main(WsServerStop.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:183)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:163)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:973)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:245)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:73)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:521)
    at com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(AdminClientFactory.java:331)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorNotAvailableException: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind]
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:338)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.<init>(SOAPConnectorClient.java:175)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Error opening socket: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind; targetException=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error opening socket: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: NET_Bind]
    at org.apache.soap.transport.http.SOAPHTTPConnection.send(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.soap.rpc.Call.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient$4.run(SOAPConnectorClient.java:303)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:296)
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: Stack trace would be useful. ADMC0016E - very general error. It should have a cause. Second is a WinSock Proxy Client. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000011239520. BTW: End of life support 6.1 has been very very long time ago.

Comment: I will try and provide stack traces tomorrow. I know 6.1 is wayyyyy old but its what my company still uses. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the netstat command and search on all the default ports assigned to your JVM. This way you can see if one of the several ports that the JVM uses is being used by some other app. It may not be only your soap port causing the issue, but one of the many other defined ports on the container. You can also try and telnet to all the JVM ports in order to see if another app is listening on that specific port.